# APA-cite using biblatex returns only in-text citation?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I guess I was more used to seeing numbering such as these -- [1].

The following lets me to compile the file okay, but

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,babel=other]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{main.bib}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
```

the return results such as:

According to a study done by Kent and Giles (2017), student teachers who use technology in their lessons tend to continue using technology tools throughout their teaching careers. [http://www.citationmachine.net/apa/cite-a-book]

Except in my case Kent and Giles (2017) would follow after the period with no context whatsoever (as I intend to just cite with number at the end)

Is this the common expected return format from APA-citation? Or are there variants I could use?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected output. `biblatex-apa` is designed to exactly reproduce the requirements of the APA. If you want a numeric citation style, then you don't want APA. Just use `\usepackage{biblatex}`.

Comment: Also, `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}` is not needed for newer versions of `biblatex` and should not be used for numeric style.

Comment: And the `babel` option is deprecated. You should use `autolang=other` instead.

Comment: If you give a parenthetical citation at the end of a sentence as in "After the intervention, children increased in the number of books read per week (Smith & Wexwood, 2010)." the APA would prefer `\parencite` (Kent and Giles 2017) instead of `\textcite` Kent and Giles (2017). See https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/01/writing-in-text-citations-in-apa-style.html. `\textcite` is used if the author names serve as subject or object in your sentence and can not be removed without impacting the structure of your sentence.

Comment: Turns out I do need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}`, I added after numerous web surfing. Thanks all.

Comment: That lines is only needed if you are using an outdated version of `biblatex` or `biblatex-apa` (for example on Overleaf). It is not needed with current versions of the two packages.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is expected. `biblatex-apa` implements the style requirements of the *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association* as much as is possible with `biblatex`.

APA style puts citations in parentheses (`\autocite`; `\parencite`) or just the year in parentheses for a citation replacing the subject of a sentence (`\textcite`).

Here's a MWE showing a full set up with `babel` and `csquotes`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% For older installations you may need
% \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{document}

You can put citations in parentheses with \verb|\parencite|
\parencite{aristotle:poetics}. It's also possible to use \verb|\autocite|
\autocite{aristotle:poetics}.

There is also \verb|\textcite|: \textcite{aristotle:rhetoric} said something
interesting about rhetoric.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output]